# How to prevent postfix rewriting recipient email addresses?

Tags: postfix

I've setup a postfix server which appears to be running fine.

`foo.com` is its primary domain,

`bar.com` is a secondary domain which used solely as another name/alias for `foo.com`.

I have the following functional configuration:

**/etc/postfix/main.cf:**

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = foo.com
virtual_alias_domains = bar.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_aliases
```

**/etc/postfix/virtual_aliases:**

```
@bar.com     @foo.com
```

This seems to work as intended.  Any email that comes in for `user@bar.com` is mapped to `user@foo.com` and is delivered to `user@foo.com`'s mailbox.

The problem comes when an undeliverable email is sent to `unknown_user@bar.com`.  Postfix maps it through to `foo.com`, finds no valid recipient, then bounces the email.

The bounce message looks like this:

```
<unknown_user@foo.com>: unknown user: "unknown_user@foo.com"
Reporting-MTA: dns; mx.foo.com
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; par@example.com

Final-Recipient: rfc822; unknown_user@foo.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; unknown user: "unknown_user@foo.com"
```

The bounce message has rewritten all the `bar.com` references to `foo.com`.

Since the sender created an email for `unknown_user@bar.com`, I think all the references to `@foo.com` in the bounce message are confusing.  Furthermore, I'd like to hide the fact (from the casual user, more or less) that `foo.com` is really `bar.com`.

Is it possible to configure postfix to only do the virtual_alias rewriting *internally*?  In other words, try to forward to `foo.com`, but on failure send back a bounce that indicates the user couldn't be found at `bar.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted my question to the postfix-users mailing list and received this reply, which illustrated why the alias configuration I was using was a bad idea and what to do to correct it:

> Yes, that's the problem with wildcard rewrites; postfix cannot
>   validate the recipient before delivery, making you a backscatter
>   source.
>
> Rather than wildcard rewrites, use 1-1 user mappings. If there are
>   more than a handful, use your favorite scripting language to create
>   the file automatically.
>
> ```
> user1@example.com user1@example.org
> user2@example.com user2@example.org
> ```
>
> Noel Jones